# pandas groupby with value_counts(normalize=True) return dataframe instead of series?

Tags: python, pandas

Not the data I am using, but best reproducible example I can think of:

```
    test = pd.util.testing.makeMixedDataFrame()
    grouped = test.groupby(['C', 'B'])['A'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

give a series:

```
C     B    A  
foo1  0.0  0.0    1.0
foo2  1.0  1.0    1.0
foo3  0.0  2.0    1.0
foo4  1.0  3.0    1.0
foo5  0.0  4.0    1.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

I want to have a dataframe with 4 columns (C, B, A, and the other unnamed), but have not been able to get this.

I tried `reset_index()` onf `grouped`, but get `*** ValueError: cannot insert A, already exists`

Comment: Use `test.groupby(['C', 'B'], as_index=False)['A'].value_counts(normalize=True)`

Comment: I think you needn't `groupby` and you can use `df.value_counts(['C', 'B', 'A'], normalize=True).reset_index()`

Comment: @mozway that gives : AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_counts'. I am really stuck on this

Comment: @mozway nevermind just had to use a newer version of pandas